# C# Validation Controls in custom WebControl classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

I have custom classes inheriting from the `WebControl` class, and I'm essentially programmatically building a form with web server controls. My goal is to be able to add validation controls to this form, which will ultimately be rendered into a `string` in which I will return to the web service caller.

*(Note: The page calling this web service is a Cold Fusion page `.cfm` not your typical `.aspx` or `.ascx` page)*

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542(v=vs.90).aspx) states:

> Validation controls can be used with any controls you put on an
>   ASP.NET Web page, including both HTML and Web server controls.

First of all, is it even possible to achieve validation through this manner with .Net's Validation Web Server Controls, because I don't see  any indication in Microsoft's documentation?

If so, simply rendering the validation controls isn't enough because it doesn't return any `ViewState` data nor the client-script which handles client-side validation on form post. Perhaps this is where the `ScriptManager` would come into play?

I've included my code for rendering the programmatically build form for clarification.

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
// Build <form> using my custom FormBuilder class
FormBuilder form = new FormBuilder() { Method="POST", ID="frmTest" };
// Add TextBox web server control
TextBox txtCertificate = new TextBox() { ID = "txtCertificate" };
// Add validator and associate to TextBox
RequiredFieldValidator rfvCertificate = new RequiredFieldValidator() { ControlToValidate = txtCertificate.ID, ErrorMessage = "Certificate required." };
// Add submit button
Button btnSubmit = new Button() { ID = "btnSubmit", Text = "Submit" };
// Bind the server controls to the form control
form.Controls.Add(txtCertificate);
form.Controls.Add(rfvCertificate);
form.Controls.Add(btnSubmit);
// Finally, return the rendered string
form.RenderControl(writer);
return writer.InnerWriter.ToString();
```

Comment: out of interest, dare I ask why you aren't just building the form directly in ColdFusion, or redirecting the user to an .aspx page when you need to display this form?

Comment: @ADyson We've got a confusing structure here were we have two server-side technologies and will eventually transition to pure ASP.NET, therefore in order to future proof all of our work, we implement all the functionality in .Net and make it available through the use of web services. We don't use `.aspx` pages yet, and we'd rather not continue developing forms in Cold Fusion as we'd like to move away from it soon.

Comment: ok I see. I'm not convinced your approach is really future proofing though, cos building forms dynamically like that in ASP.NET Forms doesn't work very well (partly for the reasons you've discussed, like viewstate etc). I actually think you'd get a better result using .NET MVC - it's cleaner, quite a bit closer to the way the raw web works, and more likely to be amenable to returning views on the fly which have been requested by another service. If it were me, and wanted to migrate to a .NET frontend, I'd just go for it (and use MVC) rather than trying this sort of hybrid